# Quitting Python socket client with open connection?

Tags: python, sockets, signals, exit

The following script receiving data from a [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) connection does not react to the CTRL+C signal sent in order to exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
"""
import socket
HOST = '192.168.178.1'
PORT = 1012
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print 'Received', repr(data)
s.close()
```

How can the program be modified so that program input or the default signal causes the infinite loop to be broken in order to end the program gracefully?

Comment: For a similar problem in server situation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148062/python-socket-accept-blocks-prevents-app-from-quitting

Answer (score 0):

Use Select

```
import socket
import select

HOST = '192.168.178.1'
PORT = 1012
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setblocking(1)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
time_out=None
ready=[[s],[],[], time_out]

if ready:
   s.recv(1024)

s.close()
```

Comment: Your example exits once something has been received. My intention is to contiuously receive and only exit on user input (CTRL+C signal). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to close the socket from another thread as shown by S. Prasanna in his [blog article](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/08/non-blocking-sockets.html).
Another may be to catch the signal somehow.